# Flask Sqlalchemy one to many foreignkey error

Tags: python, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I made two simple classes as model:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'winwin'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///abc.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), unique=True ,primary_key=True)
    fb_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True,)
    login = db.relationship('Login', backref='user')


class Login(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True ,primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


with app.app_context(): //add some test datas
    aaa = User(email='111@123.com',fb_id = 111)
    bbb = User(email='222@123.com',fb_id = 222)
    ccc = User(email='333@123.com',fb_id = 333)
    ddd = User(email='444@123.com',fb_id = 444)
    eee = User(email='555@123.com',fb_id = 555)

    db.session.add_all(['aaa,bbb,ccc'])
    db.session.commit()

    aa = Login(email='111@123',password='111',user_id=user.id)
    bb = Login(email='222@123',password='222',user_id=user.id)

    db.session.add_all(['aa,bb'])
    db.session.commit()
```

When i run in vscode it throw me an error:
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped
it seem told me the the parent's table can't be found, but i have already set the foreignkey and relationship.

Anyone konws what i did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `db.session.add_all(['aaa,bbb,ccc'])` is wrong - you you pass the actual user objects that you want to save, but you are passing strings.  Do `db.session.add_all([aaa, bbb, ccc])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.add_all` expects a list of model instances as its argument, but you are passing a list containing a string.

In instead of

```py
db.session.add_all(['aaa,bbb,ccc'])
```

pass the objects that you created, like this:

```py
db.session.add_all([aaa, bbb, ccc])
```

Comment: thanks very much! i watched many video said that are['aaa,bbb,ccc']